# XCode: "To download this update...". Is this dialog normal?

Tags: xcode

I'm getting a dialog box asking to enter my apple developer id & password in xcode. It just says something like "To download this update enter your information." then i goes away.

Is this normal? Seems to me that this would be the perfect way for a trojan to get my apple id and pwd!

Answer (score 0):

It has just happened to me, too (with the current GM Seed version). I was creating a new project when the pop-up dialog appeared.

To be on the safe side, I changed my password immediately after the incident.

What were YOU doing in Xcode when it happened to you? Are you using Xcode 3.2.2, too?

Anybody else having this issue?

The only explanation I found is here:
  http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2010/Mar/msg00265.html

Then, under /Developer/..., I found a .docset file with a time stamp corresponding to the point in time (plus a couple of minutes) when I had entered my credentials.

However, when I tried to log out & in again, open Xcode - Preferences - Documentation and initiate another download, Xcode did NOT ask me for my Apple ID/PDW again; instead, it asked me for the admin password as usual (I mean - usual for installations; the dialog box looked a bit different). So I am still wondering ...

Regards,

Karel

Comment: I don't remember what I did when it happened :P I'm on the GM seed now but this happened before as well. I have to take a closer look once it happens again. This is strange... I changed my login too...